# DataFrame - Row wise arithmetic with criteria

Tags: python, pandas

in VBA (Excel), most algorithms have to be done in a looping style. E.g. we want to find all rows where a column ("A") is "x" and then add to another column in that row the value from a row where column ("A") is "y".
How does one approach a specific problem like that in pandas?

To generalize: I'd like to go through each row of a DataFrame and use it's values as criterias to select another row(s) from the same DataFrame and do some math on the values from those rows.

In a real life example:

```
Sub SomeCode()

Dim vArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

vArr = Selection

For i = LBound(vArr) + 1 To UBound(vArr)
    If vArr(i, 2) = "S1" Then
        If vArr(i, 8) >= "2019-13" Then
            If vArr(i, 7) = "Chat" Or vArr(i, 7) = "Email" Then
                For j = LBound(vArr) + 1 To UBound(vArr)
                    If vArr(j, 2) = "S1" And vArr(j, 8) = vArr(i, 8) And vArr(j, 6) = vArr(i, 6) Then
                        If vArr(j, 7) = "Phone" Then
                            vArr(j, 9) = vArr(j, 9) + vArr(i, 9) * 0.05
                        ElseIf vArr(j, 7) = "SMS" Then
                            vArr(j, 9) = vArr(j, 9) + vArr(i, 9) * 0.95
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
                vArr(i, 9) = 0
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

Selection = vArr

End Sub
```

Dataset being something like:

```
ID     Country  Version  Partner  SOME  Location  Site  Channel  Weeknum  contacts 
1099   UK       OP1      0        0     0         0     Email    2019-08  -31
1242   UK       OP1      0        0     0         0     Phone    2019-47  -49
1599   UK       OP1      0        0     0         1     SMS      2019-40  0
1817   UK       OP1      1        1     1         2     SMS      2019-50  0
2539   UK       OP1      0        0     0         3     Chat     2019-44  94
3889   UK       OP1      0        0     0         4     SMS      2019-42  0
4106   UK       OP1      0        0     0         5     SMS      2019-51  -62
4248   UK       S1       2        1     2         6     Email    2019-37  0
5895   UK       S1       1        1     1         2     Email    2019-20  0
6328   UK       S1       0        0     0         7     Email    2019-37  0
6355   UK       S1       0        0     0         7     SMS      2019-12  0
6419   UK       S1       0        0     0         7     Phone    2019-24  0
6486   UK       S1       0        0     0         8     Chat     2019-39  91
6549   UK       S1       0        0     0         8     Email    2019-50  98
6568   UK       S1       0        0     0         8     SMS      2019-17  0
7587   UK       S1       0        0     0         9     Email    2019-48  77
7798   UK       S1       3        1     1         10    Email    2019-51  0
8185   UK       S1       0        0     0         5     Email    2019-22  70
8827   UK       S2       0        0     0         11    Email    2019-40  1
9983   UK       S2       0        0     0         1     Phone    2019-52  70
10193  UK       S2       1        1     3         12    Chat     2019-02  0
11053  UK       S2       0        0     0         13    Chat     2019-30  0
11707  UK       S2       0        0     0         9     Email    2019-08  -27
11859  UK       S2       3        1     1         10    Chat     2019-04  0
12243  UK       S2       0        0     0         4     Phone    2019-24  -77
```

Comment: could you please post your desired output in regards to the dataset you have posted

Answer (score 0):

Row selection can be done quite easily in pandas by using for example:

```
dfAx = df[df.A == x]
```

This selects all rows for which the value in column A equals x.
It is not entirely clear to me what you mean with 'then add to another column in that row the value from a row where column ("A") is "y"'. But you could for example just select all the rows for which the value of column ("A") does equals y, like this:

```
dfAy = df[df.A == y]
```

After that you can perform operations on both dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

**In `pandas` you can do multiple condition selection of rows by [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).**

For example, here's some of your conditions from your VBA code, done in `pandas` way:

```
df[((df['Version'] == 'S1') & (df['Weeknum'] == '2019-13'))]
```

You then can combine it with `.loc` operator to performa mathematic operation on selected rows:

```
df.loc[[((df['Version'] == 'S1') & (df['Weeknum'] == '2019-13')), 'contacts'] = df['contacts'] + df['contacts'] * 0.05
```

**Note**: this is an example and not your complete adapted code. Please, adapt the rest of it understanding these basics of pandas :)

Comment: Thanks for that! Indeed, this works nicely. The thing is that I would like to add 5% of a value from another row, where Version = S1 and the Channel is Phone instead of e.g. SMS.

    df.loc[[((df['Version'] == 'S1') & (df['Weeknum'] == '2019-13') &     (df['Channel']=='Phone'), 'contacts'] = df['contacts'] + df['contacts'](<- This value from the row where Version =S1, Week = 2019-13 but channel = "SMS") * 0.05

Comment: As I said, understanding these basics, you can easily adapt your VBA code to the `pandas` code that suits you. Take your time, experiment and make adaptation of your VBA an exercise for yourself to completely understand the concepts. Good luck with `pandas`! :)